# BigCommerce Price Display - Show raw price

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

In BigCommerce using the standard handlebars syntax {{price.with_tax.value}} price is displayed as 319.99. I would like to display this price without the decimal in raw format as 31999. Is this possible to retrieve in BigCommerce?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [multiply Handlebars helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#multiply) to get the result you desire.

```
{{multiply price.with_tax.value 100}}
```